# mysql table record not being consumed by Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I just started learning kafka and I am running kafka 2.13-2.80 on windows server 2012 R2. I started zookeeper using the following:

```
zookeeper-server-start.bat ../../config/zookeeper.properties
```

I started kafka using the following:

```
kafka-server-start.bat ../../config/server.properties
```

I started a connector with the following:

```
connect-standalone.bat  ../../config/connect-standalone.properties  ../../config/mysql.properties
```

The content of my mysql.properties file is as follows:

```
name=test-source-mysql-jdbc-autoincrement
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/DBName?user=username&password=userpassword
mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=id
topic.prefix=test-mysql-jdbc-
```

I started a consumer with and without a partition option:

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat -topic test-mysql-jdbc-groups -bootstrap-server localhost:9092 -from-beginning [-partition 0]
```

All seemingly started without issues but when I add a record to my mysql table called groups, I do not see it in my consumer. I checked all the various logs. The only error messages I saw were in the state-change.log and they looked like the following:

```
ERROR [Broker id=0] Ignoring StopReplica request (delete=true) from controller 0 with correlation id 5 epoch 1 for partition mytopic-2 as the local replica for the partition is in an offline log directory (state.change.logger)
ERROR [Broker id=0] Ignoring StopReplica request (delete=true) from controller 0 with correlation id 5 epoch 1 for partition mytopic-1 as the local replica for the partition is in an offline log directory (state.change.logger)
ERROR [Broker id=0] Ignoring StopReplica request (delete=true) from controller 0 with correlation id 5 epoch 1 for partition mytopic-0 as the local replica for the partition is in an offline log directory (state.change.logger)

ERROR [Broker id=0] Received LeaderAndIsrRequest with correlation id 1 from controller 0 epoch 2 for partition mytopic-0 (last update controller epoch 1) but cannot become follower since the new leader -1 is unavailable. (state.change.logger)
ERROR [Broker id=0] Received LeaderAndIsrRequest with correlation id 1 from controller 0 epoch 2 for partition mytopic-1 (last update controller epoch 1) but cannot become follower since the new leader -1 is unavailable. (state.change.logger)
ERROR [Broker id=0] Received LeaderAndIsrRequest with correlation id 1 from controller 0 epoch 2 for partition mytopic-2 (last update controller epoch 1) but cannot become follower since the new leader -1 is unavailable. (state.change.logger)
```

I also notice this message in zookeeper

```
INFO Expiring session timeout of exceeded (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
```

Please could anyone give me pointers as to what I could be doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Does your `groups` table have a primary key with auto-increment enabled?

Comment: Hello @RahulSharma . Yes the table has a primary key and it seems that autoincrement is set because whenever I run the INSERT INTO table VALUES....clause, I don't insert anything into the id column but it still ends up being generated. I didnt set up the db but have accees to it.